# События jQuery( анимация бургер меню)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Есть код, который плавно меняет значение свойства, нужно чтобы при **втором** нажатии на элемент значение менялось !!!
вот моя попытка, но получеться что через две секунды пропадает меню

```
$('.icon').click(function(){
   $('.links').animate({
        opacity: '1'
}, 1000
);
});

$('.icon').click(function(){
   $('.links').animate({
        opacity: '0'
}, 1000
);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно проверять текущее значения свойства и в зависимости от него устанавливать значение. Если `opacity` 0, то установить 1, если нет, то установить 0

```js
$('.icon').click(function(){
  if($('.links').css('opacity') == '0'){
    $('.links').animate({
      opacity: '1'
    }, 1000);
  }else{
    $('.links').animate({
      opacity: '0'
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
.links{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon">icon</div>
<div class="links">links</div>
```

Comment: @Вадим_Лешкевич Спасибо!)